# filesystem error(12)

Tags: database, blackberry

i got a file system error(12) in in blackberry application when creating a sqlite database. can plz help me what is that error

Answer (score 0):

to create a database using sqlite you need
URI object,and path

you need to create a SDCard using the simulator

dbName="NameOfDB.db";
path="file:///SDCard/Databases/"+dbName;
uri = URI.create(path);

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: thank u sir, i solved my problem but another problem created that Statement st = FirstSQLiteApp.sqliteDB.createStatement( "CREATE TABLE 'Employee' ( " +
                    "'Name' TEXT, " +
                    "'Age' INTEGER )" );
    st.prepare(); it gives wrong sql statement error

Answer (score 0):

My colleague just wrote this great post about [Using SQLite in Blackberry Applications](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/BLOGS/2011/03/29/Using+SQLite+in+BlackBerry+Applications). It touches upon file system error 12, as well as in which situations you cannot use SQLite on a blackberry.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the app using a simulator first crate a folder (say) SDCard and then create a subfolder Databases.
And when run the app,tke the menu 'simulate'> Change SDCard,click on 'Add Directory'Then browse fothe folder SDcard and select it and then run the app.

If you are debeg using a phone,After debeging ,you must disconnect the code from the phone and then run.
You can also check whether the database is created on the phone using 'mass mode'(when connected to a system using code).

Answer (score 0):

Solution file system error 12:

To open a database, you can use `theopenmethod` or `theopenOrCreatemethod`, both in the `DatabaseFactory` class.

You can open multiple read-only connections to a database, but only one read-write connection can be made at the same time.

If you want to open a database as both read-write and read-only, open it as read-write first. An attempt to open a database as read-write when it is already open (either as read-write or read-only) will generate "File system error 12", which indicates that there was an attempt to open more than one read-write connection to the same database.

To close a database, use the `close` method. To ensure that `close` is always called, you should call it in a finally block.

```
Database _db = null;
public static final String DBName = "file:///SDCard/Mobion/mobion_music.db";

URI uri = URI.create(DBName);
if (!DatabaseFactory.exists(uri))
{
  createDB(uri);// create database DBName
}
else
{
  _db = DatabaseFactory.open(uri, true);
  _db.close();
  _db = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
}
```